# Can not hide the button of table row using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting one issue while trying to hide button after a button click using Angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
    <tr ng-repeat="code in ListOfGeneratedCode">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{code.name}}</td>
        <td>{{code.no_of_voucher}}</td>
        <td>{{code.expired_date}}</td>
        <td>{{code.voucher_amount}}</td>
        <td>
            <input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='View' ng-click="viewVoucherCodeData(code.voucher_code_id);">
        </td>
        <td><img ng-src="upload/{{code.image}}" name="pro" border="0" style="width:50px; height:50px; border:#808080 1px solid;" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='Send' ng-click="sendVoucherCode(code.voucher_code_id);">
        </td>
        <td ng-hide="editButton">
            <a ui-sref="code">
                <input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='Edit' ng-click="editVoucherCodeData(code.voucher_code_id);">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td ng-hide="delButton">
            <a ui-sref="code">
                <input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-red' value='Remove' ng-click="deleteVoucherCodeData(code.voucher_code_id);">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My controller side code is given below.

```
$scope.sendVoucherCode=function(voucherCodeId){
        $scope.editButton=true;
        $scope.delButton=true;
}
```

Here my problem is when user is clicking on `Send` all row's `edit and delete` button has disappearing.I need when user will click on `send` button the respective row's `edit and delete` button should disappear.Please help me.

Comment: Can you please show a demo to help one in better understanding?

Comment: The problem is that all rows refer to one and the same $scope.editButton/$scope.delButton. So all rows get impacted if these values get changed. You need to add a scope variable for these buttons for each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing code needs some modification as the key for edit and delete is same, so it clears the whole. Please refer the code below:

**HTML**

```
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
    <tr ng-repeat="code in ListOfGeneratedCode">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{code.name}}</td>
        <td>{{code.no_of_voucher}}</td>
        <td>{{code.expired_date}}</td>
        <td>{{code.voucher_amount}}</td>
        <td><input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='View' ng-click="viewVoucherCodeData(code.voucher_code_id);"></td>
        <td><img ng-src="upload/{{code.image}}" name="pro" border="0" style="width:50px; height:50px; border:#808080 1px solid;" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='Send' ng-click="sendVoucherCode(code.voucher_code_id);">
        </td>
        <td ng-hide="code.editButton">
            <a ui-sref="code">
                <input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='Edit' ng-click="editVoucherCodeData(code.voucher_code_id);">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td ng-hide="code.delButton">
            <a ui-sref="code">
                <input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-red' value='Remove' ng-click="deleteVoucherCodeData(code.voucher_code_id);">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**JS**

Add this after `$scope.ListOfGeneratedCode` has been instantiated.

```
angular.forEach($scope.ListOfGeneratedCode, function (value, key) {
    value.push('editButton', false);
    value.push('delButton', false);
});
```

Append/change the existing methods with:

```
$scope.sendVoucherCode = function (id) {
    angular.forEach($scope.ListOfGeneratedCode, function (value, key) {
        if (value.voucher_code_id == id) {
            value.editButton = $scope.delButton = true;
        }
    });
}

$scope.editVoucherCodeData = function (id) {
    angular.forEach($scope.ListOfGeneratedCode, function (value, key) {
        if (value.voucher_code_id == id) {
            value.editButton = true;
        }
    });
}

$scope.deleteVoucherCodeData = function (id) {
    angular.forEach($scope.ListOfGeneratedCode, function (value, key) {
        if (value.voucher_code_id == id) {
            value.delButton = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this `$scope.delButton` or `value.delButton`..?

Comment: sorry it should be `value.delButton`.